# пайтон не выдаёт ошибок.И я сам не вижу её.Однако телеграм не выводит кнопки моего бота, что делать?

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    
    
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    sell_btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('найти аккаунт')
    markup.add(sell_btn1)
```

Comment: Вы не запустили бота, или это не весь скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

После добавления кнопок, вы должны отправить сообщение пользователю. Также я заметил, что у вас нет infinity_polling. Вот как должен выглядеть ваш код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
     markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
     sell_btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('найти аккаунт')
     markup.add(sell_btn1)
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reply_markup = markup)

bot.infinity_polling()
```